# Hbase KeyValue size too large

Tags: hbase

I'm using Spark Streaming to download webpage and insert into Hbase. I encounter the following exception:

```
WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 13.1 in stage 21.0 (TID 121,test1.server): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: KeyValue size too large
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.validatePut(HTable.java:1378)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.validatePut(HTable.java:1364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.doPut(HTable.java:974)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.put(HTable.java:941)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.write(TableOutputFormat.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.write(TableOutputFormat.java:87)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1000)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:979)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried to increase the hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize, and set hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize=0 means there is no limitation. Additionally, I increased hdfs.blocksize=256M. But when I restarted the cluster, I still encounter the same error:keyvalue to large.
Any ideas please, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize is a client side property. You will need to set this property either in hbase-site.xml on your client node. Or you can set this property in your code in Configuration object.
There is no need to restart HBase for that property.